# How to Generate incremental range of numbers

Tags: php

I want to generate range of numbers based on to total number of users in my database

```
<?php
//Let's assume the total number of users is 100

foreach( range(0, 100, 20) as $number){
   $ranges=$number.'-'.($number+20);
echo'<button>'.$ranges.'</button>';
}

//Result: 
0-20
20-40
40-60
60-80
80-100
100-120
?>
```

What i needed is 0-20, 21-40, 41-60, 61-80, 81-100.
I need to stop at 100 i.e the total number of users and not up to 100-120

or if you have a better approach

Comment: How about `100 - 1` to make the end non-inclusive?

Comment: Is there an reason why it shouldn't be 0-19, 20-39...

Comment: @ggorlen Good idea...but that means i will need to put it in array and then reverse it to be 1-100 i guess

Comment: @Nigel Ren It could be.

Comment: So your first group (0-20) will be one unit greater than each of the next groups (21-40, ...)?

Comment: @trincot exactly..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So two issues to deal with:

- Stop at 100. Then you just decrease the loop's stop value a bit (e.g. reduce by 1, i.e. 99)
- Start at one more than the previous range's end value, except for the first range which should start at 0. You can add `!!$number` to achieve that. This is a boolean which is true when `$number` is non-zero, and will coerce to a 0 or a 1, exactly what is needed.

Code:

```
foreach(range(0, 100 - 1, 20) as $number) {
   $ranges = ($number + !!$number) . '-' . ($number + 20); 
   echo '<button>' . $ranges . '</button>';
}
```

Comment: Omg! So perfect.